# How could one pixelate 3D models like in the photos below?

Tags: modifiers, pixel-art

I want to pixelate 3D models for a game project, i don't know if it's possible to do in blender but what would be the best way to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling anti aliasing ?

Answer (score 2):

To pixelate the image, as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxQDcRpQUDk) by Dantti, first render your image then use this node setup in the *Compositor*: *Render Layers > (Distort) Scale > (Filter) Pixelate > (Distort) Scale > Output* and choose a value of 0.1 in the first *Scale* and 10 in the second, or 0.05 and 20 and so on, so that it reduces your image and bring it back to its original scale with pixelation:

[image]

To increase the anti-aliasing effect maybe you need to use materials wih *Emission* node only, but as Lolock says it's not clear what you want to do with your blend file as you're talking about a game.

If you want to kind of pixelate the object itself, use the *Remesh* modifier (*Blocks* mode), you need to set the *Octree Depth* value to choose the cube size:

[image]

Comment: I didn't mean pixelate like this, i want to pixelate them like just in the images. Pixels look like they are being distorted

Comment: But doing this in Blender is useless if you want to use these models in a game. The reason why these old games were aliased like that is specifically because they had no anti-aliasing and were displayed in a very low resolution. So just do that in your game engine and you will have the same result.